# Error in MenuHelper after copying htdocs folder to other server

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

I just copied my htdocs folder to anther pc with a clean new xampp and made a copy of the database too. When i try to access the site the php error log shows this error:

> [13-Jun-2014 18:34:07 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  array_merge() [http://php.net/function.array-merge'>function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\View\Helper\MenuHelper.php on line 74
>
> [13-Jun-2014 18:34:07 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\View\Helper\MenuHelper.php on line 85

My other page which was in the same htdocs folder is running fine (it isn't using cakephp). Any ideas what could have happened? Any idea how to find out where this is called since it seems to be a cakephp-Helper?

**EDIT:**
Seems I missed 2 lines in the php_error.log:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\View\Layouts\default.ctp on line 2
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: menu in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\View\Layouts\default.ctp on line 82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a new version of xampp but did not update cakephp to the newest version. After doing so everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

some see me the same, that's what I did, just copy the folder app, after creates a new project and copy the app folder and replaces the app folder. and shuld be found. I look the reason of the problem and just read about the cookies and cache. And the option that a give you is more easy.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand a word you're saying. Could you explain further? Or try google translator?